# Video Tag in Chrome Browser requesting incorrect range when seeking progress bar to random location. Firefox is working flawlessly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, fastapi

I have FASTAPI server which can server partial content, Response status 206.

```
@video_router.get("/video/file/{folder}/{name}")
async def video_endpoint(folder: str, name: str, range: str = Header(None)):
    CHUNK_SIZE = 2048*2048
    video_path = Path(f"./media/{folder}/{name}")
    video_size = video_path.stat().st_size
    start, end = range.replace("bytes=", "").split("-")
    start = int(start)
    if start + CHUNK_SIZE > video_size:
        end = video_size
    else:
        end = start + CHUNK_SIZE

    with open(video_path, "rb") as video:
        video.seek(start)
        data = video.read(end - start)
        headers = {
            'Content-Range': f'bytes {start}-{end}/{video_size}',
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'
        }
        return Response(data, status_code=206, headers=headers, media_type="video/mp4")
```

From react frontend I am requesting this URL to give partial content.

```
<video
          controlsList="nodownload"
          key="abc"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          poster={poster_url}
          controls
          src={video_url}
          type="video/mp4"
          preload="metadata"
        />
```

This is working flawlessly in firefox browser, but in Google Chrome when I am seeking the progress bar to any location either backward or forwards. The video player gets hung/stuck. Post playing the Pause/Play button, video starts to play from starting i.e. bytes=0-.

When debugging this range parameter which is passed in header I notice that the chrome browser is requesting the incorrect bytes i.e. bytes=INCORRECT_NUMBER-. Additionally that INCORRECT_NUMBER is same for any position in progress bar. Please check the below images.

[IMAGE1: Time was equal to 15 seconds but bytes requested was the ending bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9VBm.png)

[IMAGE2: Time was equal to 2:54 minutes but bytes requested was the ending bytes identical to previous image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hRaB.png)

After this operation as you can see the video tag is no longer requesting any data from the FASTAPI server.

I tried changing headers, other react-video players and iframe tag.

I am expecting to stream videos through fastapi server serving partial content. Suggestion for alternative or workaround of video tag is much appreciated.

Comment: The issue seems to be on the client side - I think it would help if you shared more of your client code for people to look at, or even better a link to a test site if you have one

Answer (score 0):

**video_size - 1**
**end - start  + 1**

Above modifications are required.